# Google AMP, how can i implement a classic popup with cookie?

Tags: cookies, amp-html

do someone has an idea about this? Because it seems that custom javascript is not allowed. Plus, the pages will be cached in the "cloudflare.com" way. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Discussed here:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/740

Will be implemented as part of this apparently (though not done yet):
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/902

For now I would say https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues is the best place to check for AMP related info.